# Debugger operation is in progress

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio

I recently downloaded visual studios for windows and am using Python 3.6. VS gives me the message "Debugger operation is in progress" and has a loading bar when f5 or 511 are pressed. After the message goes away the debugger does not open. If I select Project > start with/without debugging  programs run fine and the debugger opens regularly. What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 3):

Just ran into the same problem. Right click on your main script and select "set as startup file". Then try F5 again